# tmux how to force kill-session

Tags: tmux

I use tmux on mac os x 10.11.5 but suddenly it stopped working correctly.
When i type tmux it does keep attaching to my grouped tmux session "ruby" instead of creating a new one.

```
$ tmux ls
ruby: 2 windows (created Fri Jun 24 15:37:29 2016) [80x23]
```

ok, i'll kill the ruby session:
    $ tmux kill-session -t ruby

but it's still there and keeps me attaching to the ruby session.

```
$ tmux ls
ruby: 2 windows (created Fri Jun 24 15:37:29 2016)
```

I tried detaching, too:

```
$ tmux detach -s ruby
```

But it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
$ tmux new session -t test
```

still attaches to my ruby session.

Is there another way to kill the ruby session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out this issue was caused of the ruby gem tmuxinator. after i uninstalled tmuxinator it stopped automatically attaching.